# Setting Time Format for jspinner in swings

Tags: java, swing, time, jspinner

I am working in a java swing application. In that application i have to take time input from user.
I need to make a JSpinner for the time, only in the hh:mm am/pm format. i searched in properties but could not get this format.

Please suggest me some way to display time in hh:mm am/pm format. I thank to all your valuable suggestions.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can set an editor and a date model like this:

```
SpinnerDateModel model = new SpinnerDateModel();
model.setCalendarField(Calendar.MINUTE);

spinner= new JSpinner();
spinner.setModel(model);
spinner.setEditor(new JSpinner.DateEditor(spinner, "h:mm a"));
```

Comment: Thanks for answering. but above code is giving me result in "dd-mm-yyyy" format. I need in hh:mm am/pm format. what can be a suitable format to pass instead of "dd-mm-yyyy" for getting time in hh:mm am/pm format only.

Answer (score 9):

Thanks for answering Guillaume. Your answer is working for me after making a small change i.e.

spinner.setEditor(new JSpinner.DateEditor(spinner, "h:mm a"));

This gives me an appropriate format.