# Java JTextField with date and time format

Tags: java, swing, date, datetime

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [JTextField time in HH:mm:ss](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5914909/jtextfield-time-in-hhmmss)

Is't possible to make a JtextField like this: enterHour/enterMin/enterSec, which is the "/" is uneditable? and retrieve those data?

Comment: You could have a read of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5914909/jtextfield-time-in-hhmmss and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2234726/jformattedtextfield-input-time-duration-value and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9483716/java-jformattedtextfield-time-formating and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11051250/strict-24-hour-time-in-jformattedtextfield. You might also find http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5515413/jspinner-exclusively-for-time and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3845374/setting-time-format-for-jspinner-in-swings of some use

Comment: And if you're really desperate you could try http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11881301/best-way-to-constrain-user-to-enter-a-time-in-a-jtextfield/11881681#11881681 (note the answer uses a proto type field, so it has issues) (actually the question and accepted answer would also help ;) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11881301/best-way-to-constrain-user-to-enter-a-time-in-a-jtextfield)

Comment: Thx i'll try to read the links

Comment: Don't forget, if you find any of the links useful, an up-vote wouldn't go astray (for the posters that is) ;)