# Java bean (a graphic widget) or other technique to allow a use to select a time?

Tags: java, swing, time, javabeans, time-select

Does anyone know of any good Java bean (a graphic widget) or use of Swing, that allows a user to choose a time? They only need to select the **hour** and **minute** they want, not the second or millisecond etc.

I have found a good date selection bean (JCalendar), but I am in desperate need of one that allows the user to easily select the time.

This could be done by clicking on some kind of clock or graphical element (**I don't want the user to manually enter the time because the minutes must go up in fives** (e.g. 10:00 or 10:05 or 10:10 etc.)

**I have tried using a JSpinner**, but this doesn't work because I am not entirely sure how to format it properly so that the user doesn't enter the wrong time (the minutes must go up in 5's, etc.).

**At the moment I am using 2 combo box's**, one for the hour (from 00 to 23) and one for the minute (from 00 to 55) but I find this annoying to use sometimes, due to misclicking, and it is not very visually attractive or easy to understand.

[An example of what I am using](http://s9.postimg.org/d140c20sb/timeseletor.png)

Can anyone suggest a Java bean that fulfills this need?

Comment: Uh, "Java bean" is confusing here :) You probably mean a (graphic) widget?

Comment: thank you, I've made the change

Comment: possible duplicate of [Setting Time Format for jspinner in swings](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3845374/setting-time-format-for-jspinner-in-swings)

Comment: @trashgod I have already tried using a JSpinner, but it may result in the user entering a time value that is not valid (i.e. the minutes may not be in multiples of 5). Is there a way to disallow the user entering a value? Also is there a way to make the minutes section of the Spinner go up in 5's? If so, I could use a JSpinner.

Comment: I guess you can always resort to two separate spinners, withe one model listening to the other; see also this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2902275/230513).